# Ruby bundle command not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command, bundle

When I use the command `bundle exec newvm.rb`, I get the message that

```
bundler: command not found: newvm.rb
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

I know there are several people having this problem but with all the solutions that worked for other people, non have worked for me.

I have done the following:

1. `gem bundler install`
2. `bundle install`
3. `which gem => /home/$user/.rbenv/shims/gem`
4. `which bundle => /home/$user/.rbenv/shims/gem`
5. `rbenv rehash`(after bundler install)
6. `.bashrc` export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" eval "$(rbenv init -)"

But im still having the problem that bundler: command not found. And i cant get any further, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a ruby script, `ruby newvm.rb` should be enough.

If you want to run it under bundle context, then do:

`bundle exec ruby newvm.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced issues running the bundle install command from my project. I found you had to change these two files:(both in your Ruby bin directory)

bundle.bat

bundler.bat

Both files are pointing to incorrect references to the Ruby path. I changed them to point to the correct Ruby path and now the command works. This may help others I hope. This is the example for my system.  You would need to change yours according to where you've installed Ruby on your system.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT

@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\bundle" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

GOTO :EOF

:WinNT

@"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```